# python UTF-8 decimal to string

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, lxml, iso-8859-1

I am getting below xml which contains `ñ` (equivalent to UTF-8 dec as per https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec&unicodeinhtml=dec)

```xml
<user>
     <name>mariap</name>
     <full-name>Maria Pe&#195;&#177;a</full-name>
     <uid>2007</uid>
     <class>super-user</class>
</user>
```

how to convert above thing in python to print it as

```xml
<user>
     <name>mariap</name>
     <full-name>Maria Peña</full-name>
     <uid>2007</uid>
     <class>super-user</class>
</user>
```

Comment: That is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) which has been HTML encoded. `&#195;&#177;` does not represent "ñ". If possible this needs to be fixed at the source.

Comment: Could you give us a minimal example of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: we are trying to get back same content back in script side. check the XML response response sent from device https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/junos-config-files-loading.html
section: Understanding Character Encoding on Devices Running Junos OS

Comment: `import html;html.unescape( 'Pe&#195;&#177;a').encode( 'latin', 'backslashreplace').decode('utf-8')` should return `'Peña'`